# 'IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor when calling subprocess in a daemon

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
if args.daemon:
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid > 0:
        sys.exit(0)

    os.close(0)
    os.close(1)
    os.close(2)

main()


def main():
    # some code
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

I get IOError: [Errno 9] only when main is called as a deamon ie (forked off process and stdin/stdout/stderr closed

i suspect its from closing those pipes but if i don't, my program wont return. is there way to execute subprocess within a daemon?

Comment: What do you mean by `my program won't return`? You closed stdout and stderr. By definition, it _shouldn't_ be returning.

Comment: if you run it in shell it wont return unless i close 0,1,2. so thats what i want to do. but i think thats what causing IOError. so i want to be able to close and still call subprocess

Comment: You said that. What do you mean by return, though? Like, relinquish control of the shell to you?

Comment: @JakobLovern yes i.e. run in the background

Comment: Which of the two processes is using the console, the child or the parent? It should be the parent. When you call `os.fork`, it should push the child out on its own, and only signals directed at its PID are able to touch it. There's no need to close stdin/stdout/stderr because it (the child) never had them open to begin with.

Comment: im sorry but i have a hard time understanding what you are saying and what you are getting at. im telling you the behavior i see when i actually run the program. try out yourself. if you dont close then prompt wont return. process is running in foreground, not back ground

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code:

```
if args.daemon:
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid > 0:
        sys.exit(0)
    os.close(0)
    os.close(1)
    os.close(2)
```

to:

```
 if args.daemon:
    stdin = '/dev/null'
    stdout = '/dev/null'
    stderr = '/dev/null'

    try:
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid > 0:
            # exit first parent
            sys.exit(0)
    except OSError, e:
        sys.stderr.write("fork #1 failed: %d (%s)\n" % (e.errno, e.strerror))
        sys.exit(1)

    # decouple from parent environment
    os.chdir("/")
    os.setsid()
    os.umask(0)

    # do second fork
    try:
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid > 0:
            # exit from second parent
            sys.exit(0)
    except OSError, e:
        sys.stderr.write("fork #2 failed: %d (%s)\n" % (e.errno, e.strerror))
        sys.exit(1)

    # redirect standard file descriptors
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stderr.flush()
    si = file(stdin, 'r')
    so = file(stdout, 'a+')
    se = file(stderr, 'a+', 0)
    os.dup2(si.fileno(), sys.stdin.fileno())
    os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
    os.dup2(se.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())
```

and subprocess no longer raises IOError